Inaccurate Location on iOS Devices using Geolocator Package in Flutter
On iOS devices where the location data returned using   geolocator: ^13.0.2 is very generic, and the precision is significantly lower compared to Android devices. This occurs despite using LocationAccuracy.high in the location settings. Facing this on multiple iOS devices. Any suggestion?
Configure location settings as follows for iOS:
_locationSettings = AppleSettings(
    accuracy: LocationAccuracy.high,
    activityType: ActivityType.fitness,
    distanceFilter: 100,
    pauseLocationUpdatesAutomatically: true,
    // Only set to true if our app will be started up in the background.
    showBackgroundLocationIndicator: false,
  );


Future<void> _updateLocationStatus() async {
  _positionStream = Geolocator.getPositionStream(locationSettings: _locationSettings)
      .listen((position) {
    debugPrint("Position: Latitude: ${position.latitude}, Longitude: ${position.longitude}");
  });
}

I am getting these different values in the same location. In Android :

In iPhone :

